# The Mysql command line doesn't launch

Tags: mysql, sql, database, command-line

i just installed Mysql 5.6.20 and set the path in the system
when i try to launch the Mysql command line it starts and closes immediately.
any solution ?

Comment: can you walk through the steps you took to launch it? Also does it start and immediately close or are you not able to get it to start at all?

Comment: i just clicked on the application "mysql command line" also tried to run it as administrator
the application starts and closes immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the command line (start menu, run, cmd)

Type in:

```
cd c:\xyz\mysql\bin
```

Where xyz is the full path to your mysql's bin folder (this is probably the same as where you currently are, clicking on the program itself)

Then type in (in the command line):

```
mysql --user=root --password=xyz db_name
```

Where root is either root (if you want to login as root) or the username that you want to login as. And change xyz to the password for that user. Change db_name to the name of the database you want to login to.

Then you can run a query, like:

```
select * from tablename limit 1;
```

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: thank you it works! but what about the command line that comes with mysql ? is there any solution for that ?

Comment: That is the program you're actually using, you just have to launch it from within the Windows command line. When you do step 1 above you're actually pointing the Windows command line to that folder. When you do the connection string, starting with "mysql" the mysql.exe program is used inside that folder. When you were clicking on it, you had started it, essentially, but didn't tell it to do anything (your connection string wasn't there).

Comment: On a sidenote, if you don't want to have to re-perform step1 every time you open the command line, you can skip that by setting the path as a system variable, using the instructions here: http://www.devarticles.in/miscelleneous/fixing-mysql-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-windows7/